# Удалить пустые слова (' ') из текста в Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

```
b = [[a,b,c,' '], [d,e,' ', f], [q,w, ' ', ' ']]
```

type(b) = list

как удалить ' ' из b?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему del работает не так?

Answer (score 2):

> Почему del работает не так?

Это можно легко отладить:

```
In [132]: for i in range(len(b)):
     ...:     for j in range(len(b[i])):
     ...:         try:
     ...:             if b[i][j] == ' ':
     ...:                 del b[i][j]
     ...:         except IndexError:
     ...:             print(b[i])
     ...:             print(i,j, j <= len(b[i])-1)
     ...:
['d', 'e', 'f']
1 3 False
['q', 'w', ' ']
2 3 False
```

В цикле вы итерируете по исходным индексам списков и после того как вы удалите пустой элемент размер списка уменьшится на 1. Соответственно используя исходный размер вы "прийдёте" к несуществующему элементу.

Первый такой элемент: с "координатами" `i==1, j==3`. Т.е. вы пытаетесь выбрать элемент с несуществующим индексом:

```
In [133]: ['d', 'e', 'f'][3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-52d249955cc6> in <module>()
----> 1 ['d', 'e', 'f'][3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

Один из многих возможных вариантов решения:

```
new = [[el for el in lst if el and el.strip()] for lst in b]
print(new)
```

Результат:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['q', 'w']]
```

Альтернативный вариант:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] = [el for el in b[i] if el and el.strip()]
```